# Does INCLUDing Columns to Non-Clustered Index DUPLICATE values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, include, indexing, non-clustered-index

If I use INCLUDE clause and add some columns to a Non-Clustered Index, does this mean I am storing the data both on INDEX and on its PAGE -meaning at least DOUBLING the space consumed-?

Comment: Yes. Indexes implement a space/time tradeoff. You increase space; you decrease execution time (for some queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This space doubling also goes for index keys. Indexes can make up a significant amount of storage space.

A covering index with all table columns will be almost exactly the size of the original table, just sorted differently.

Comment: So, the space is almost doubled when I INCLUDE a column to a Non-Sluctered INdex. In addition to this I add extra I/O time when it comes to INSERTs.

Comment: That's true. The value of included columns is that you don't need a key lookup to obtain the value.